# Hiding overflow on HTML tag makes browser jump to top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, overflow

When I set the style on the html tag, like so in AngularJS:

```
angular.element($document[0].documentElement).css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

The page jumps to the top of the page. How can I prevent this?

I am trying to display a full page overlay, and when I try to scroll, the background scrolls. It doesn't scroll when I set the overflow: css style on the html tag. That has lead me to this problem.

Comment: What is the overall goal of hiding the document overflow?  Why does it occur in the first place?

Comment: @JoshBurgess I am trying to display a full page overlay, and when I try to scroll, the background scrolls. It doesn't scroll when I set the `overflow: css` style on the html tag. That has lead me to this problem

Answer (score 0):

When you hide the document, you're essentially telling the browser to not scroll.  That's why you're being directed to the top of the page, as the page in essence no longer extends beyond the viewport.

While not every browser will send you to the top of the page (expected behavior here would be to lock the user into the page where they're at), something like active tracking of a `hash` *(e.g. mypage.com/#ShowLogin/)* like Angular often uses for routing could very easily cause the page to jump to the top of the screen.

---

## Edit:

If you want to keep the background so that it doesn't scroll with the page, use the property `background-attachment`:

```
html, body {
  ... /* Other code here */
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: By background, I meant the content behind the overlay (you can see it if the overlay opacity is less than 1)

Comment: Have you tried setting the property on the `body` element as opposed to the `html` element?

Comment: Yes. I've applied it to both